# Any way to show div on same page using jquery? Div class has parameters. So normal Div.show() is not working as we can't pass parameter object in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <!-- Search results tab -->
        <div id="testingClass" style="display:none;">
            <h3 class="theme-background">Course Results (${courseResponseList.getCourses().size()})</h3>
            <br>
            <c:forEach items="${courseResponseList.getCourses()}" var="course"
                varStatus="loop">
                <form action="/search/course/edit" method="post">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-shadow">
                        <div id="${course.getCourseID()}-panel-heading" class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#${course.getCourseID() }" aria-expanded="false">
                            <c:set var="showAssignButton" value="false" />
                            <c:forEach items="${enrolledCourseList}" var="courseEnrolled"
                                varStatus="loop">
                                <c:if
                                    test="${courseEnrolled.getCourseID() eq course.getCourseID()}">
                                    <c:set var="showAssignButton" value="true" />
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <tags:courseNameAndDescription courseResponse="${course}"
                                showAssignButtonValue="${showAssignButton}" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="${course.getCourseID() }" class="panel-body collapse">
                            <tags:courseMetaData courseResponse="${course}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </c:forEach>
        </div>

Want to show above div.


jquery script.

<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
$("#searchButton").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = [];

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType : "application/json",

                        url : "/search/getCourseList",

                        data : $("#courseSearchForm").serialize(),


contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
                        success : function (data) {



                         var jsobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                         console.log(jsobj);


//WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE ?

                         alert("reached");

                        },
                        error : function(e) {

                            alert("Failed to search....");
                        }
                        });


 });
</script>
```

I'm getting the courselist from ajax call but I'm not able to display it on same page. Jquery.load(url) will also not work as jsp file is in WEB-INF. So we can't access it through url. 
Div id="testingClass" is present in the same file.(courseSearchPage.jsp).I want to show this div when I click on search buttom.

Comment: Trying to follow your issue... simply doing $('#testingClass').show(); doesn't work?

Comment: It's not taking the "data". So page is not getting populated.

Comment: Can you try console.log(data); and see what your browser's developer tools show?  Can you confirm that your ajax call is returning the data you expect.

Comment: I verified that. i'm getting the expected data by logging both "data" as well as "jsobj".

Comment: What does 'data' contain? Is it the html you posted above?

Comment: No..data contains the json received on successful execution of Ajax call

Comment: I'm not sure how to help, if that div is there and it's just hidden, you should be able to call $('#testingClass').show(); after your ajax success handler.

Comment: Getting blank div on it. Expected output https://imgur.com/DBXIn8y . But I'm getting https://imgur.com/I6iYz6T

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to best understand your problem, this code snippet works for me.

```js
$("#searchButton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://httpbin.org/get?test=chakram",
    data: $("#courseSearchForm").serialize(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#testingClass').show(); //ADD THIS LINE HERE
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert("Failed to search....");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="searchButton">click me</button>
<div id="testingClass" style="display:none;">
  <h3>your div has now been shown!</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Not getting the course results present in the output of ajax call on view. Getting blank div on it. Expected output https://imgur.com/DBXIn8y . But I'm getting https://imgur.com/I6iYz6T